# Laptop starting up to BIOS everytime. OS boots after exiting from BIOS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios

Toshiba Satellite L850 is always booting to the BIOS, not the OS. Always I have to manually exit the BIOS to boot the OS. The HDD is the first priority in the BIOS. Some disk error check is also showing every time after booting the OS.

PS: I tried reinstalling the OS to Windows 7, getting the same issue. I've enabled and disabled fast boot and I choose CMS over UEFI, getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your BIOS to default ?

Comment: Yeah! I tried. No change at all

Comment: Look for a BIOS update on Manufacturer site. I don't think this is Windows issue & re-installing it won't do any good

Comment: That's weird. What if you unplug the keyboard?

Comment: There is a problem with your hard drive, I would back up your data and prepare for a hard drive replacement, this is default behavior when there is a hardware issue and since you get a disk error check your hard drive is failing.

Comment: As I mentioned, a disk error check _CHKDSK_ is functioning on every boot, I suppressed that using some manual error checking for _Dirty_ disks and troubleshooting for the disk. **[This link](http://www.hightechdad.com/2013/04/25/how-to-stop-chkdsk-from-running-on-every-boot-up/)** may give help on this issue better

Comment: As @Moab mentioned, I also think this could be a hard disk or some other issue. I used the above technique only to suppress the error check. It won't rectify BIOS starting up issue!